# Play Framework 2.3.1 Promise exception handling within inner class

Tags: java, exception, error-handling, playframework, promise

What is the right approach in order to implement a correct exception handling within a WS API Request?

An example:

```
F.Promise<List<String>> modulesPromise = WS.url(requestUrl).setAuth(apiUser, apiPassword).get().map(
            new F.Function<WSResponse, List<String>>() {
                public List<String> apply(WSResponse response) {
                    List<String> modules = new ArrayList<>();

                    JsonNode json = response.asJson();
                    for (JsonNode node : json) {
                        modules.add(node.get("name").toString().replace("\"", StringUtils.EMPTY));
                    }

                    return modules;
                }
            }
    );

    modulesPromise.recover(new F.Function<Throwable, List<String>>() {
        @Override
        public List<String> apply(Throwable throwable) throws Throwable {
            Logger.error("error", throwable);
            return new ArrayList<>();
        }
    });
```

If an exception occurs in that case within the inner class, the exception ll be thrown further. Its the same problem with the method .onFailure(). Isn't it the best way to use a try catch block in order to catch potential exceptions? The recover and the onFailure method seems to be useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, it appears that `recover` isn't going to do you much good. `recover` is used for provide a default value when the `Promise` fails (e.g. an exception is thrown inside it).

In this case you're operating on a `List` where calling `node.get("name").toString()` will throw an exception if `name` is not a field in the `JsonNode`. This will cause the `Promise` to fail entirely, and so the rest of your list is gone. You *could* wrap it in a try/catch, but it's not necessary.

Since `node.get("name")` returns `null` if there is no `name`, then you should just check for `null` before operating on it:

```
 for (JsonNode node : json) {
     if(node.get("name") != null)
         modules.add(node.get("name").toString().replace("\"", StringUtils.EMPTY));
 }
```

So the answer really is that it depends on your use case. Often, if an exception occurs within the `Promise`, you *want* it to fail. Then the rest of your code can handle it appropriately. However, if an exception can occur that would generally not affect the final result, then either catch or it handle it otherwise to prevent it from failing the `Promise` (checking the null, in this case).

Comment: Thanks for your answer but my problem is another. How should I handle Exceptions that're caused by the unavailability of the webserver? Is the onFailure method from the F.Promise the right way in order to handle such kind of exceptions? When it is - how I've to use it?
Or is it better to execute the code block in my question above in a try catch block in order to provide a correct and good exception handling?

Comment: If an exception is thrown because the web server is unavailable, then the `Promise` will fail, and you should allow that to happen. That's why `Promise` has successful and failed states. You *can* `recover` it to a successful `Promise` by mapping exceptions to an actual result, but you don't need to.

Answer (score 0):

You were *thisclose*. What you had was essentially:

```
promise = WS.get
    .map;
promise.recover;
```

What you originally wanted is:

```
promise = WS.get
    .map
    .recover;
```

Your instinct was right: while `try/catch` handles exceptions synchronously, inline with the currently executing thread, methods like `recover` handle exceptions asynchronously while those promises are being evaluated/fulfilled. The key is that each promise is separate, and those methods that return a promise are actually returning a new promise.

The `get` promises to return the result of the HTTP call. The `map` promises to take that result and extract the "name" from each node. The `recover` promises that *if* there is an exception *anywhere in the chain*, it will return a new empty list instead. But in your example, that last promise isn't assigned/used anywhere, so no one is listening/watching/awaiting that promise; they are awaiting the `map`, which can fail (either itself or the `get`). Note that the `recover` code will still execute if there is an exception, but no one wants the result.

Whether to use `recover` or let the entire call fail is a separate question. For example, if you are composing a response from several other calls, maybe you could replace a failed third-party call with "not available", or simply omit the elements that did not work.

While `recover` returns a new promise, `onFailure` is `void`. It's what your example does: do something when there is an exception, but no one is dependent on it. For example, suppose you want to log whenever a third-party call fails. You could do that inside the `recover` -- log then return an empty list -- or you can do it separately: the `recover` returns the empty list, and the `onFailure` logs. That way, the functionality is more composable; and again, it's important that to differentiate the various promises:

```
promise = WS.get
    .map;
promise.onFailure;
promise = promise.recover;
```